# Insert colored line at the top of TRichEdit

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7

I'm using a `TRichEdit` in order to show the last operations that have been done in my application. The first line of my `TRichEdit` should be the last operation. If the operation failed, I would like to put this line in red.

My problem is that I am not able to insert a colored line at the top of my `TRichEdit`. Here is what I've tried:

```
RichEditLog.SelAttributes.Color := clBlack;
RichEditLog.Lines.Insert(0, 'Operation 1 OK');
// RichEditLog.Lines.Add('Operation 1 OK');

RichEditLog.SelAttributes.Color := clRed;
RichEditLog.Lines.Insert(0, 'Operation 2 failed');
// RichEditLog.Lines.Add('Operation 2 failed');

RichEditLog.SelAttributes.Color := clRed;
RichEditLog.Lines.Insert(0, 'Operation 3 failed');
// RichEditLog.Lines.Add('Operation 3 failed');

RichEditLog.SelAttributes.Color := clBlack;
RichEditLog.Lines.Insert(0, 'Operation 4 OK');
// RichEditLog.Lines.Add('Operation 4 OK');
```

The problem is that my `TRichEdit` only apply the first change of color and keep it for all the lines. If I use `Add()` instead of `Insert()`, the colors are changing but the line are inserted at the end of my `TRichEdit`.

My question is : **Is there an easy way to get the results I'm looking for ?**

Comment: Zero length selection, specify selection attributes, assign to SelText.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set the selected start and length to 0 if you want to insert at the beginning:

```
RichEditLog.SelStart := 0;
RichEditLog.SelLength := 0;
RichEditLog.SelAttributes.Color := clBlack;
RichEditLog.Lines.Insert(0, 'Operation 1 OK');
```

Alternatively, instead of `RichEditLog.Lines.Insert()` you can assign the text to `RichEdit.SelText`, but then you need to add the new line characters yourself, f.ex.:

```
RichEditLog.SelText := 'Operation 1 OK'+sLineBreak;
```

Either way, when applied to your test code the result is:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Did you try playing with `SelAttributes` and `SelText`, `SelStart`, `SelLenght` ?

```
Insert(0,'This is blue text.');
RichEdit1.SelStart := 0; 
RichEdit1.SelLenght := //end;
RichEdit1.SelAttributes.Color := clBlue;
```

Comment: I tried to use `SelAttributes` as showed in my question but it only works if I use `Lines.Add` but doesn't work if I use `Lines.Insert`. The color changes  once and never change anymore after that.

Comment: I am suggesting you to insert not formatted line using `Insert ` and then using `SelStart`, `SelLength` for applying the style to the selected text

Comment: Thank you, I used Tom's answer but it looks similar to your answer. ;)

Comment: yes ... his code is more correct, I was not using real Delphi compiler ... but only my mind and memory :-)